# Amcharts - Error while trying to create top and bottom value axes in lower screen widths

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to make Amcharts column chart which will rotate and become a horizontal bar chart at lesser screen width. I want two value axes - top and bottom in the mobile screens (lesser than 600px).

I am trying to add this code to the Amcharts javascript API in the responsive part but it is not working and giving error -

```
,
        "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "top"
  },{
    "position": "bottom
  }
  ],
```

This is my snippet -

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginRight": 70,
  "panEventsEnabled": false,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Click on Country to see Visitor details"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025, // to ensure that the smaller bars' labels are fully clickable
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FCD202",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#F8FF01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#B0DE09",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#04D215",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D8ECF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D52D1",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#2A0CD0",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#8A0CCF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#CD0D74",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }],
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": [{
      "maxWidth": 600,
      "overrides": {
        "rotate": true,
        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
        "columnSpacing": 5,
        "minMarginLeft": 38,
        "depth3D": 0,
        "angle": 0,
        "graphs": [{
          "hidden": false
        }, {
          "columnWidth": 1
        }],
        "legend": {
          "enabled": true,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "labelText": "Country",
          "fontSize": 14
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "top"
  }
  ],
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "labelText": "[[category]]",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "id": "label-only",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true, //hide by default for larger screen sizes
    "columnWidth": .6,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "hiddenvalue", //use hidden value to make labels clickable
    "includeInMinMax": false //make sure the graph doesn't affect the value axis min/max when zooming.
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "depth3D": 10,
  "angle": 45,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "classNameField": "Ctglabel",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minHorizontalGap": 50,
    "title": "Country",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

document.getElementById('resize').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.resized === "no") {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv").style.width = "500px";
    e.currentTarget.dataset.resized = "yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv").style.width = "100%";
    e.currentTarget.dataset.resized = "no";
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis tspan {
  cursor: pointer;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis text.amcharts-axis-label tspan:hover, 
g.amcharts-graph-label-only text tspan {
  text-decoration: underline;
  fill: red;
}

text.amcharts-axis-title {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<button id="resize" data-resized="no">Resize chart</button>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message hints at what's wrong: `"too many index-based overrides specified for object array property: valueAxes"`. Basically, the responsive plugin cannot create an additional value axis (or any other property) when a rule is triggered and it can only modify properties that currently exist in the chart. This means that you need to define your second value axis in your config upon chart creation so you can modify the second value axis in your width rule. In addition, a value axis must be associated with at least one graph in order to be visible and you can't assign a graph to multiple value axes through the [`valueAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#valueAxis) property. This means you need yet another hidden graph just for the second axis. Note that you can't use the label graph as it will not render the labels on top of the visible bars.

Here's an outline of changes you need to make.

1) Add a second value axis in makeChart with [`includeHidden`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#includeHidden) set to false so that it doesn't render in the non-rotated view. You also need to set its [`id`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#id) so you can assign it to a graph object.

```
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }, { //second axis to toggle on smaller screen sizes.
    "id": "second",
    "includeHidden": false
  }],
```

2) Add an invisible graph that references this second axis' id in the `valueAxis` property:

```
  "graphs": [
  // other graphs omitted
  {
    //invisible graph for the second axis
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "valueAxis": "second"
  }]
```

3) Modify your valueAxes responsive rule and set the second value axis' `includeHidden` property to true so that it will display upon resize:

```
  "responsive": {
    // ...
    "rules": [{
      // ...
      "overrides": {
        // ...
        "valueAxes": [{
          "position": "top"
        }, {
          "position": "bottom",
          "includeHidden": true
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginRight": 70,
  "panEventsEnabled": false,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Click on Country to see Visitor details"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025, // to ensure that the smaller bars' labels are fully clickable
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FCD202",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#F8FF01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#B0DE09",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#04D215",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D8ECF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D52D1",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#2A0CD0",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#8A0CCF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#CD0D74",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }],
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "addDefaultRules": false,
    "rules": [{
      "maxWidth": 600,
      "overrides": {
        "rotate": true,
        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
        "columnSpacing": 5,
        "minMarginLeft": 38,
        "depth3D": 0,
        "angle": 0,
        "graphs": [{
          "hidden": false
        }, {
          "columnWidth": 1
        }],
        "legend": {
          "enabled": true,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "labelText": "Country",
          "fontSize": 14
        },
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
          "position": "top"
        }, {
          "position": "bottom",
          "includeHidden": true
        }]
      }
    }]
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }, {
    "id": "second",
    "includeHidden": false
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "labelText": "[[category]]",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "id": "label-only",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true, //hide by default for larger screen sizes
    "columnWidth": .6,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "hiddenvalue", //use hidden value to make labels clickable
    "includeInMinMax": false //make sure the graph doesn't affect the value axis min/max when zooming.
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, {
    //invisible graph for the second axis
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "valueAxis": "second"
  }],
  "depth3D": 10,
  "angle": 45,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "classNameField": "Ctglabel",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minHorizontalGap": 50,
    "title": "Country",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

document.getElementById('resize').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.dataset.resized === "no") {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv").style.width = "500px";
    e.currentTarget.dataset.resized = "yes";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv").style.width = "100%";
    e.currentTarget.dataset.resized = "no";
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis tspan {
  cursor: pointer;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis text.amcharts-axis-label tspan:hover,
g.amcharts-graph-label-only text tspan {
  text-decoration: underline;
  fill: red;
}

text.amcharts-axis-title {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<button id="resize" data-resized="no">Resize chart</button>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where did you see the error message ? I just got a white screen as error

Comment: Your browser's developer console is your friend. It is usually accessible by hitting F12, but [this answer lists the shortcuts for each browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337).